# How do you ordinal encode a variable in R based on another column?

Tags: r, regression, ordinal-classification

I have an ordinal variable called **Product.Package.Level** and would like to ordinal encode it
and order them based on the sum of the number or average number of the variable **Leads**. How exactly do I go about doing this?

[Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVibq.png)

This can be easily be done in python with the feature engine package.

Comment: If your data frame is called `df` you can do this with `reorder` using `df$Product.Package.Level <- reorder(df$Product.Package.Level, df$Leads)`

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Use `dput(dataset)` or create a simple example from scratch. In this case, you're only interested in two variables, so make it very basic - `dat <- data.frame(Product = c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c"), Leads = c(1,2,3,1,1,4,5))` or something similar.